# Rabbitmq in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, kubernetes

I'm trying to do something very simple and it doesn't work. I must be doing something stupid but I just can't see it. I hope someone can...

When I run the `rabbitmq:latest` Docker image on my local docker I can connect to it successfully:

```
docker run -p 5672:5672 -d rabbitmq
telnet <dockerMachineIp> 5672
Trying x.y.z.w...
Connected to x.y.z.w.
```

Now I'm deploying the image into k8s:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: rabbitmq
  name: rabbitmq
  namespace: uat
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      env: uat
      run: rabbitmq
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        env: uat
        run: rabbitmq
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: rabbitmq
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: rabbitmq
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5672
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          tcpSocket:
            port: 5672
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          tcpSocket:
            port: 5672
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 150Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 150Mi
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  observedGeneration: 2
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

And I create a service for it:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
  namespace: uat
spec:
  ports:
  - name: tcp5672
    port: 5672
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5672
  selector:
    run: rabbitmq
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

The image successfully deploys:

```
2016-08-16T06:08:15.903787400Z =INFO REPORT==== 16-Aug-2016::06:08:15 ===
2016-08-16T06:08:15.903793115Z started TCP Listener on [::]:5672
2016-08-16T06:08:15.911128257Z  completed with 0 plugins.
2016-08-16T06:08:15.911479872Z 
2016-08-16T06:08:15.911492347Z =INFO REPORT==== 16-Aug-2016::06:08:15 ===
2016-08-16T06:08:15.911497759Z Server startup complete; 0 plugins started.
2016-08-16T06:11:00.901609310Z
```

But after this my other application trying to connect to `tcp://rabbitmq:5672` receive a `Connection Refused`. When I test it myself:

```
kubectl run --namespace uat -i --tty busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never -- sh
/ # telnet rabbitmq 5672
Connection closed by foreign host
```

In the rabbitmq logs I can see:

```
2016-08-16T07:38:48.465296167Z =INFO REPORT==== 16-Aug-2016::07:38:48 ===
2016-08-16T07:38:48.465302171Z accepting AMQP connection <0.3666.0> (10.244.66.6:50968 -> 10.244.64.4:5672)
2016-08-16T07:38:48.465391749Z 
2016-08-16T07:38:48.465408673Z =ERROR REPORT==== 16-Aug-2016::07:38:48 ===
2016-08-16T07:38:48.465414738Z closing AMQP connection <0.3666.0> (10.244.66.6:50968 -> 10.244.64.4:5672):
2016-08-16T07:38:48.465420105Z {handshake_timeout,handshake}
```

What I'm doing here is so simple I don't see what I missed.

### EDIT

I had left that issue on the side because I had no time to work on it. When I tried again a few weeks later it just started working. I didn't change the version of k8s or made any changes to the infrastructure. I'm afraid I don't know what happened

Answer (score 0):

`5672` is the AMQP port is not accessible using `HTTP`.

The management UI uses the port `15672`, but you have enable it:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

see this https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html

then you can use:  http://server-name:15672/

Comment: sorry it was a typo, I didn't mean `HTTP`. My other docker images are indeed trying to use the AMQP port. Doing a `telnet` doesn't use `HTTP` and I'm expecting it to work. At the moment I'm not planning to use the management UI.

Comment: This http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/handshake-timeout-handshake-td30085.html will help you

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't. The fact that it works when I run everything on the localhost but not in k8s makes me think that it would be some config issue in k8s.

Comment: @phoenix7360 did you manage to find what really happened? I'm facing the exact same issue